# How do I find rows that don't exist in a table using hive sql query?

Tags: sql, hive

My data is like this:

| ID | Stage_1 | Stage 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | F |
| 1 | B | G |
| 1 | C | H |
| 2 | A | F |
| 2 | B | G |
| 2 | C | H |
| 3 | A | F |
| 3 | B | G |
| 4 | A | F |
| 4 | B | G |

I want to find the number of unique ID's for which `Stage_1 = A` exists but `Stage_2 = H` does not exist. Here, for `ID = 3` and `ID = 4`, A exists in `Stage_1` but in `Stage_2` there is no `H` for `ID = 3` or `ID = 4`.

So the expected result here would be 2.

`Outer join` won't apply as I'm getting data from only one table in our database using hive sql terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to left join the table to itself and count the nulls

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID)
FROM your_table t1
LEFT JOIN your_table t2
  ON t2.Stage_1 = t1.Stage_1
    AND t2.Stage_2 = 'H'
WHERE t1.Stage_2 = 'A'
AND t2.ID IS NULL
```